# How to run an Ansible command with the user id root

Tags: ansible, root, sudo, su

I have an application that I need to install using root using Linux (CentOS).

When I install the application manually, it doesn't work when I type `sudo <command>`. I actually need to login as root using `sudo su -` and then I type in my command. I've used:

`remote_user: root`

or

`su: root`

and even used something like

```
command: sudo su -
command: <command>
```

But the command is not run in the same way as I would do login manually?  I don't get the same results.

How I can I run my command with the user id `root` with Ansible?

Comment: Check `$PATH` on `root` account.

Comment: I noticed that there's a difference when I manually [vagrant] ssh into the box.  When I do this under the vagrant user id the path has the following:  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/home/vagrant/bin  but when I "sudo su -" and log in as root I see that the variable is now "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin"   Can you explain what to check and why/what to remediate?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you set up your machine for doing things with the management account.

Your environment likely needs to be set up properly in the sudoers file, eg:

```
---
- name: set a sudoers.d file
  hosts: www
  tasks:
    - name: Copy /etc/sudoers.d/env_keep into place
      copy:
        content: "Defaults env_keep += \"PATH\"\n"
        dest: /etc/sudoers.d/env_keep
        validate: visudo -cf %s
        owner: root
        group: root
        mode: 0440
```

You can also try the new [become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) method, if you have no alternative.